# Can silicone plaster "Mepiform" be used for the atrophic scars?

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, plastic-surgery

Can silicone plaster "**Mepiform**" (that is typically used for prevention of excessive formation of scars) be used for the specific type of scars - **atrophic scars**?